# Solve using auxiliary variable

Tags: elementary-number-theory, roots

The question asks for me to solve the equation below using an auxiliary variable.

I don't know how to build the auxiliary variable for this problem, can anyone please help? Thanks.

$$10^{\log ( \log x   )}-10^{\log (16/\log x)}=6$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
10^{\log ( \log x   )}-10^{\log (16/\log x)}=6\Rightarrow 10^{\log ( \log x   )}-10^{\log 16}10^{-\log(\log x)}=6\ .
$$
Then set $10^{\log(\log x)}=t$, so your equation becomes
$$
t-10^{\log 16}\frac{1}{t}=6\Rightarrow t^2-6t-10^{\log 16}=0\Rightarrow t=-2\text{ or }t=8\ .
$$
We need to exclude $t=-2$, so the equation to be solved is
$$
10^{\log(\log x)}=8\Rightarrow 10^{\log(\log x)}=10^{\log 8}\Rightarrow \log(\log x)=\log 8\Rightarrow \log x=8\Rightarrow \boxed{x=10^8}\ .
$$

Comment: Thanks, 
sorry I had not seen, thanks for your time